# What mean file with extension "h.in"?

Tags: c, header-files

I am studying the C language, and I saw a new extension that I had not seen before.

What do files with the extension like `library.h.in` mean?

Is it as the simple header with extension ".h"? What's the difference?

Comment: Extensions are meaningless to the _C_ language

Comment: Hmm weird [this](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/in) link says they might be spyware?

Comment: @MikeChristensen I'm more suspicious of that page than of a normal `Makefile.in` or `config.h.in`.

Comment: @DanielFischer - Yea, they might just be trying to sell you virus scanners..

Answer (score 48, accepted):

These files are usually the input for [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html) which will generate final .h files.

Here's an example from PCRE:

```
#define PCRE_MAJOR          @PCRE_MAJOR@
#define PCRE_MINOR          @PCRE_MINOR@
#define PCRE_PRERELEASE     @PCRE_PRERELEASE@
#define PCRE_DATE           @PCRE_DATE@
```

Autoconf will replace all variables (`@…@`) with the respective values and the result will be a .h file.

Answer (score 22):

Typically, a `.h.in` file is a header template that is filled in to become the actual header by a `configure` script based on the outcome of several tests for features present on the target platform.

Comment: This file extension is also popular among other build tools, e.g.`cmake`

Answer (score 6):

Files ending with .in are typically template files used by a program called `configure` that generates a new file without the extension after substituting for variable expansions. I.e., if you're looking at a source tree that has files called, e.g. `Makefile.in` in the tree, then `./configure` will generate a usable Makefile that can be used to "make" from source.